# Mediawiki: Template with reference (with a template)

Tags: mediawiki

I want to make it easier for myself to create references in my wiki.

My current setup is that I have to do something like this:

```
<ref name="120507">Reference for something that happened on the {{createdate|120507}}</ref>
```

The template create date just turns the string `YYMMDD` into `dd month YYYY`

I want to simplify this by only needing:

```
{{ref|120507}}
```

But I cant seem to get the property right, and it won't traverse into the template *createdate* either. It just URL-encodes the curly brackets instead of taking the value of `{{{1}}}`.

```
<ref name="{{{1}}}">Sometext {{createdate|{{{1}}}}}.</ref>
```

This is what I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the `{{#tag}}` magic word](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aXML-style_tags#Tag_function) to do this. So, your template would look something like this:

```
{{#tag:ref|Sometext {{createdate|{{{1}}}}}.|name={{{1}}}}}
```

Although exactly this code wouldn't work correctly, because `name` cannot be an integer.

Comment: Thanks! How would I have to do it if I want `<ref name="{{{1}}}"/>`?

Comment: It's explained on the page I linked to. It's `{{#tag:ref||name={{{1}}}}}`.